# Eclipse doesn't load a plugin that i put in the dropins folder

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pde

I have a problem that eclipse won't load my plugin if i drop it into the /dropins folder. I am using eclipse Kepler (Service release 2, aka 4.3). I already tried to find a hint in the .metadata/.log file but couldn't find any.

Then I tried to open eclipse with:

```
eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug /path/to/.options
```

The .option file contains:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true
```

But the output from the console log also didn't help (The plugin is named de.jaculon.egap):

```
[p2] Mon Aug 03 12:33:47 CEST 2015 - [Start Level Event Dispatcher]     [reconciler]
[plan] de.jaculon.egap 2.2.6.rev5974
```

Furter info:

- The plugin has been compiled for "1.7" source compatibility.
- Eclipse runs under jdk1.7.0_51. So the plugin should be compatible.
- The plugin has been signed using javas jarsigner.exe.

I tried the same with Eclipse mars (4.5) and there it works. But i currently do not want to upgrade to 4.5 as i do have several plugins. Further 4.5 has other bugs i discovered so this is currently no option.

I would be very happy for any help,

Greetings Joe

### Addendum

The reason in one case was that i forgot the '.' in the Bundle-ClassPath directive:

Bundle-ClassPath: .

Comment: Last time I had this issue, the plugin wasn't compatible with my Eclipse or java version. Did you check that?

Comment: If you have checked that, you can try the "Plug-In Registry" view and check the details of the plugin, if you can find it there. The view should show dependencies for the plugin.

Comment: The plugin has been compiled for 1.7. Eclipse runs under JDK 1.7. So they should be compatible. Or are there other compatibility issues i should check? In any way i would find a hint in the logs from eclipse helpful. To your other hint. The plugin doesn't show up in the "Plug-In Registry" view.

Comment: I've had success creating a feature for my plugin then an update site for that feature, and then installing from the target Eclipse from the built update site. HTH!